# kubectl works on laptop but times out from within a docker container

Tags: docker, networking, kubectl, docker-network

Context:
I'm setting up a deployment tooling image which contains `aws-cli`, `kubectl` and `helm`. Testing the image locally, I found out that kubectl times out in the container despite working fine on the host (my laptop).

Tested with `alpine/k8s:1.19.16` image as well (same docker run command options) and ran into the same issue.

What I did:

- I'm on OS X and have `kubectl`, `aws-cli` and `helm` installed via `brew`
- I have valid (not expired yet) AWS credential (`~/.aws/credentials`) and `~/.kube/config`

  - running `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket` works on my laptop, returning the correct response
  - running `kubectl get pods -A` works on my laptop, returning the correct response
- switching to running these in containers with `docker run`. no context change. this issue exists in both the image I created and an official `k8s` tooling image from `alpine`. for simplicity reason I'll use `alpine/k8s:1.19.16` in my command

  - command for launching container console: `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=""  -e AWS_PROFILE -v /Users/myself/.aws:/root/.aws -v /Users/myself/.kube/config:/root/.kube/config -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock" -v /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock:/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock -e GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" alpine/k8s:1.19.16 /bin/bash`
  - in the launched console:

    - running `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket` still works fine, returning the correct response
    - **running `kubectl get pods -A` times out**

I compared the verbose output of `kubectl get pods --v=8` (with the same context and `~/.kube/config`):

on the host (my laptop)

```
I0826 01:24:11.999265   43571 loader.go:372] Config loaded from file:  /Users/myself/.kube/config
I0826 01:24:12.014315   43571 round_trippers.go:463] GET https://<current-context-k8s-dns-name>/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s
I0826 01:24:12.014330   43571 round_trippers.go:469] Request Headers:
I0826 01:24:12.014351   43571 round_trippers.go:473]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.24.0 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/4ce5a89
I0826 01:24:12.014358   43571 round_trippers.go:473]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0826 01:24:12.443152   43571 round_trippers.go:574] Response Status: 200 OK in 428 milliseconds
```

in the console (`docker` container):

```
I0826 08:25:47.066787      19 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /root/.kube/config
I0826 08:25:47.067505      19 round_trippers.go:421] GET https://<current-context-k8s-dns-name>/api?timeout=32s
I0826 08:25:47.067532      19 round_trippers.go:428] Request Headers:
I0826 08:25:47.067538      19 round_trippers.go:432]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0826 08:25:47.067542      19 round_trippers.go:432]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.19.16 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e37e4ab
I0826 08:26:17.047076      19 round_trippers.go:447] Response Status:  in 30000 milliseconds
```

The `~/.kube/config` was mounted correctly and the verbose log verified that it's loaded correctly, pointing to the right `https` endpoint. I tried `ssh` (by IP) to one of the master node by ip (from both container and laptop): laptop worked but the same ssh command from container timed out too.

`nslookup <current-context-k8s-dns-name>` from both container and laptop gave slightly different output.

from my laptop(host):

```
nslookup <current-context-k8s-dns-name>
Server:     10.253.0.2
Address:    10.253.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <current-context-k8s-dns-name>
Address: 172.20.50.40
Name:   <current-context-k8s-dns-name>
Address: 172.20.50.41
Name:   <current-context-k8s-dns-name>
Address: 172.20.50.42
```

from the container:

```
nslookup <current-context-k8s-dns-name>
Server:     192.168.65.5
Address:    192.168.65.5:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <current-context-k8s-dns-name>
Address: 172.20.50.40
Name:   <current-context-k8s-dns-name>
Address: 172.20.50.41
Name:   <current-context-k8s-dns-name>
Address: 172.20.50.42
```

I have a feeling that this has something to do with `docker` network but I don't know enough to solve this. I'll be deeply grateful if anyone can help explain this to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this issue is clearly a docker networking issue.

ran `tcpdump` + `telnet` on both host and container to compare the output and seems like the packets are not even routed to the host.

end up doing a `docker network prune` and this issue is resolved. nothing wrong with the setup, it's a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2820#issuecomment-1228785515) for `docker` on OSX